Seleccionar el elemento hermano en CSS
Estoy realizando un pequeño toggler y no logro hacerlo funcionar.
Estoy utilizando el selector ~ para selecccionar el elemento hermano pero no hace el cambio que espero; cuando seleccione "black" quiero que el círculo dentro del toggler vaya al lado derecho y cuando seleccione "blue" el círculo dentro del toggler vaya hacia la izquierda (como en la posición inicial).
Ya he intentado con éxito usando :not de la siguiente manera:
#blue:not(checked) ~ span>span{
    transform: translateX(45px);
}

y cambiando el order de los inputs, pero me gustaría saber por qué el siguiente método no funciona y cuál sería la manera correcta de conseguirlo.


*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

h3{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.color-opt{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1rem;
}

span{
    display: inline-block;
}

.toggler{
    background-color:pink;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    inset: 0;
    margin:auto 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

input[type=radio]{
  display:inline-block;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}

#blue:checked ~ span>span{
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
#black:checked ~ span>span{
  transform: translateX(45px);
}
<h3>Color</h3>
<div class="color-opt">
    <label for="blue">Blue</label>
    <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" checked>
    <span class="toggler">
        <span class="circle"></span>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" id="black" name="color">
    <label for="black">Black</label>
</div>




En respuesta a:

[...] me gustaría saber por qué el siguiente método no funciona [...]

El selector ~ como dice en la documentación:

[...] selecciona el segundo elemento sólo si está precedido por el primero y ambos comparten un padre común.

Es decir, que la regla:
#black:checked ~ span>span {
  transform: translateX(45px);
}

Solo funcionaria si span>span estuviera DESPUÉS de #black

En respuesta a:

[...] cuál sería la manera correcta de conseguirlo.

Diría que la regla:
#blue:not(checked) ~ span>span{
    transform: translateX(45px);
}

Es una forma elegante de conseguirlo y no veo el porqué de buscar otra solución.

Gracias. Mi error fue dar por sentado que el selector general de hermanos seleccionaba cualquier hermano del elemento y no sólo a los que le preceden.
